# How to link lists in order

Tags: python

I have multiple lists, the first index of each list are related the second as well so on and so fourth. I need a way of linking the order of these two lists together. so i have a list of teams (some are duplicate) i need an if statement that says: if theres a duplicate of this, then compare this to the duplicate and take the related value in the other list and choose the better one

```py
import sys
import itertools
from itertools import islice

fileLocation = input("Input the file location of ScoreBoard: ")

T = []
N = []
L = []

timestamps = []
teamids = []
problemids = []
inputids = []
scores = []

dictionary = {}

amountOfLines = len(open('input1.txt').readlines())

with open('input1.txt') as input1:

    for line in islice(input1, 2, amountOfLines):
        parsed = line.strip().split()
        timestamps.append(parsed[0])
        teamids.append(parsed[1])
        problemids.append(parsed[2])
        inputids.append(parsed[3])
        scores.append(parsed[4])

def checkIfDuplicates(teamids):
    ''' Check if given list contains any duplicates '''
    if len(teamids) == len(set(teamids)):
        return False
    else:
        return True

for i in teamids:
    if checkIfDuplicates(i):


    dictionary['team%s' % i] = {}
    if dictionary < amountOfTeams:
        dictionary['team%s' %]

for i in score:
    dictionary[teamid][]

print(dictionary)
```

Comment: Try iterating through both with `for i, j in zip(lst1, lst2)`.

Comment: You should provide an example of an input and expected output because the statement `"if theres a duplicate of this, then compare this to the duplicate and take the related value in the other list and choose the better one"` makes exactly zero sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. loop through each list item
2. delete item if duplicate

   `for i in list1:`
   `for k in list2:`
   `if i == k:`
   `list.remove(i)`